# Disable table of view counts on public CV?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

When viewed, my public CV lists a table of how many views my CV has gotten in total, the past month, today, etc.

This same view count is shown when you view *anyone's* public CV.

Is this something that can be made optional for the owner of the CV?

While I might certainly want to see that data, I'm not 100% sure I want everyone viewing my public CV to see that as well - I'd at least like to have the choice.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes.

The value should be private.  It is something that is not (or should not be) of value to anyone but the careers account holder.